How to inject an already generated and valid token into Swagger UI / Redocly UI of Fast API
in my company we have the following use case:

Fast api servers with /docs to show the Swagger UI or the Redocly UI.
One login to access the /docs pages.

With the out of the box setup of Fast API docs, we need to both login and generate a token using the auth modal we specify. We would like to avoid this, and using a token generated when you login to the /docs endpoint.
Do you know if this is actually possible?

Swagger UI provides the preauthorize* methods for this purpose - but you'll have to somehow inject it into the HTML of the /docs page served by FastAPI.
